# Data Provider for ODBC not found

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework

I want using PostgreSQl with ASP.NET Entity Framework. However, I can't found **Provider for ODBC**

1. I find provider in Data Connection 
   [image]
2. When i get entity, i can't found

   [image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you *install it*? If yes, which provider did you install? There are two installers for the [official PostgreSQL ODBC driver](https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/)

Comment: If you want to use EF though, why not use [NpgSQL](http://www.npgsql.org/index.html)? It includes providers both for [EF 6](http://www.npgsql.org/ef6/index.html) and [EF Core](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are using DB first approach. For this Npgsql has a [Visual Studio extension (VSIX)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RojanskyS.NpgsqlPostgreSQLIntegration) which integrates PostgreSQL access into Visual Studio. It allows connecting to PostgreSQL from within Visual Studio's Server Explorer, and you can create an Entity Framework model from an existing database.
http://www.npgsql.org/doc/ddex.html

However, a better approach would be code fisrt and using [NpgSql nuget package](http://www.npgsql.org/index.html).